# How can i customize D3 axis lable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, bar-chart

I want only the lowest value and the highest value to be showed in my x-axis of the bar chart in a D3. I m confused how to do it here is the attachment I want my axis like this. My data is in a JSON form like:

[image].

Thank you

Comment: have you tried `.tickValues([0,235])`

Comment: Try `.tickValues(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.yValue; }))`